# Image Thumbnails in wysiwyg editor

Tags: wysiwyg, directus

Is there a way to have directus insert links to thumbnails instead of the original full-size image when using the wysiwyg editor?

Context:

We have directus configured to use S3 for file uploads. Our backend directly connects to the directus db to fetch data and return it to the client in whichever form it is needed.

Now for the wysiwyg editor all html it generates is fine. However, images inserted with it always link to the original image.

In our case the client is a mobile app. Saving bandwidth with thumbnails is important because the app is used a lot without wifi.

I'd like to avoid having to parse the src tag and replace it with a different link. Mainly because it is not a simple search and replace, as the link contains the location on s3 (uuid), not the id that directus uses for thumbnails (private hash) - so I would also need to query the database a second time.

EDIT: I'm actually doing the search, query db, and replace (Optimized a bit by collecting the links, then going to the db once in a big query, then do the replace). I haven't found an easier way of doing it.